# Users can't access Advanced Poll nodes (permissions issue)

Tags: 7, users

I have [Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) control installed and I thought I had permissions figured out. I can create a new page or article and grant or deny access to Anonymous (or other users) by changing the settings on Access Control tab.

However, I've installed the [Advanced Poll](https://www.drupal.org/project/advpoll) module and I might be stuck. Advanced Poll created a special content type. To add a new poll, one does Content | Add Content | Advanced Poll This is fine and works. However, since it does not have an Access Control tab, I'm unable to give access to either Anonymous or Authenticated Users.

Permissions for Advanced Poll are:

```
Vote on Polls - Anonymous and Authenticated allowed
Cancel or Change own votes - Anonymous and Authenticated allowed
```

Permissions for Node are:

```
View Published Content: Anonymous and Authenticated allowed
```

Per the log files it is failing on node access (e.g. node/6 - Access Denied) I'm able to hit the poll page as I've allowed access to the page, but the content does not display (403 Access Denied).

Does this mean that I cannot used Advanced Poll since I've chosen to use Access Control? Or is there some other way that I might be able to let this content thru to the right users?